# unable to upload image blob from server hosting to database

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, blob

I can't upload image (blob) from server hosting to phpmyadmin, the result always be "null" but it works well in localhost.

Here is the model :

```
public function update($pic, $id, $title, $category)
{
        $fullPath = $pic["file"]["full_path"];
        $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE products SET name='$title', photo= LOAD_FILE('$fullPath') WHERE id='$id' and id_p_category='$category'");

        return $query;
}
```

I've changed the permission of the file in server, but it didn't work. Please help me to solve it. Thank you

Comment: you check $fullpath containe data?

Comment: It contains data. The file can be uploaded to server hosting well, but cant be stored to database

Comment: Can you post example of that data

Comment: the url refers to : /home/user1/public_html/apps/upload/pic1.JPG ( server hosting ) and
C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp/upload/pic1.JPG ( localhost ). In localhost works well. Anyway, I'm using sub domain 'apps' in server hosting.

Comment: Why you said is blob when data contain url and not data blob

Comment: i don't save the url into database but i save the image (blob) stored in that url. it become image (blob) in database